# Ruby 1.8.5 is missing thread extension?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, macos, build

I am trying to compile Ruby 1.8.5 on my Mac (yes, I need this specific version), but am having trouble getting the standard C extensions to work. All the Ruby 1.8.5 sources I get from [here](http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=426) don't include ext/thread sources, so I can't compile the thread.bundle extension. However, several .rb files in Ruby require this extension, so I'm a bit confused how anyone has compiled 1.8.5 Ruby on Mac before.

Does anyone know if there are precompiled archived versions of Ruby out there where I could find this? Or does anyone know why the thread extension is missing from all the 1.8.5 downloads I find? It's present in 1.8.6.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is preventing you from using 1.8.6 or 1.8.7, both of which are far more available?

Comment: I'm writing plugins for Google SketchUp, which uses Ruby 1.8.5 on OSX and there is virtually no flexibility. SketchUp also does not provide a standard installation, so developers are forced into this spiral of compiling an older version of Ruby and including it with plugins, or finding workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you compiling Ruby? From what I can tell in the SketchUp developer docs -- and I could be wrong -- SketchUp already contains its own Ruby interpreter. Or perhaps it uses the system Ruby, at least on Mac OS (the docs are ambiguous). Either way, I don't think you need to do what you're doing...

Comment: Trust me, you don't even want to know about the mess that Google has created with SketchUp's Ruby.

Comment: Well, I like SketchUp and I like Ruby, but I've never tried to use both together. I'll admit to being morbidly curious beyond the meager documentation... :)

Comment: Just stay away from the standard libraries and you will have a ton of fun programming for SketchUp. The minute you need a standard C extension or RubyGem you will plummet down the rabbit hole...